# Following a Unity-snake tutorial, but the controls have a delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controls, delay

I am following a tutorial on making a snake game in unity. The problem is there is a small but very noticeable delay when I hit a key and when the snake actually turns. The delay is inconsistent, sometimes I'm able to make a perfect U-turn other times it will skip a few blocks before the U-turn completes. It's a big deal because it's a fast game that is all about timing.

Thanks for any help! Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Snake : MonoBehaviour {
    int frame = 0;
    Vector2 dir = Vector2.right;

    void Start()
    {// repeats Move function
        InvokeRepeating("Move", 0.1f, 0.05f);
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        frame += 1;
        // Move in a new Direction?
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            dir = Vector2.right;
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            dir = -Vector2.up;    // '-up' means 'down'
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            dir = -Vector2.right; // '-right' means 'left'
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            dir = Vector2.up;
    }

        void Move() {
        transform.Translate(dir);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Discovered **few** problems with your code. It is **too** **fast** for the human eye. You are calling the function that updates the direction of the snake **every 0.05** second which may have caused the **delay**.

I added `snakeSpeed` as a variable to control the speed of the snake.You can change the value from the Editor or trough code for different levels. The **lower** the value, the **slower** the snake. The **higher** the value, the **faster** the snake is. I replaced `InvokeRepeating` with `Coroutine` which is more appropriate for what you are doing. Since you provided a full code, you get a full functioning code back.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Snake : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Vector2 dir;
        public float snakeSpeed = 0.06f; //To control the speed of the snake
        bool continueMoving = false;

        int frame = 0;

        void Start()
        {
            dir = Vector2.right * snakeSpeed;
            StartCoroutine(MoveSnake());
        }


        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            frame += 1;
            // Move in a new Direction?
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
                dir = Vector2.right * snakeSpeed;
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
                dir = -Vector2.up * snakeSpeed;    // '-up' means 'down'
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
                dir = -Vector2.right * snakeSpeed; // '-right' means 'left'
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
                dir = Vector2.up * snakeSpeed;
        }

        //Call to start moving
        IEnumerator MoveSnake()
        {
            if (continueMoving)
            {
                yield break; //Make sure there is one instance of this function running
            }
            continueMoving = true;

            //Continue moving nonstop until continueMoving is false or  stopSnake() function is called.
            while (continueMoving)
            {
                transform.Translate(dir);

                yield return null;
            }
        }

        //Call to Stop Moving Snake
        void stopSnake()
        {
            continueMoving = false;
        }
    }
```

I don't think you need the extra function call or invoke repeating but I included it just in-case you need to that in your tutorial. The **right** way to actually do this with less code is below:

```
   Vector2 dir;
    public float snakeSpeed = 0.06f; //To control the speed of the snake
    int frame = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        dir = Vector2.right * snakeSpeed;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        frame += 1;
        // Move in a new Direction?
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            dir = Vector2.right * snakeSpeed;
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            dir = -Vector2.up * snakeSpeed;    // '-up' means 'down'
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            dir = -Vector2.right * snakeSpeed; // '-right' means 'left'
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            dir = Vector2.up * snakeSpeed;

        transform.Translate(dir);
    }
```